# Can't play sound

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a method for play a sound each time this is called:

```
public static void getInformationSound() 
{
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/../Resources/Sounds/SF_Info.wav");
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(sri.Stream);
        simpleSound.Play();
 }
```

but on the line `SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(sri.Stream);` I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is my folder resources:

[image]

Maybe I wrong the URI? `Project -> Resources (Folder) -> Sounds (Folder) -> file...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mplayer.Open(new Uri(@"../../Resources/Sounds/SF_Info.wav", UriKind.Relative));
mplayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you google around a bit you will find different solutions for getting the sound player to work with a `Uri`, but almost everywhere a comment states that it doesn't work.

An easier way would be to add your soundfile to the resources of your project and instantiate the Soundplayer using this Resource.

1. Add your soundfile to your `Resources.resx`
   Open your Resources.resx, select "Audio" in the upper left and drag&drop your soundfile in here. Don't forget to give it a name, `SF_Info` in the example below.
2. Instantiate your `SoundPlayer`:
   `SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.SF_Info);`

Comment: A resource (.resx) would 100% be the correct way to go with something like this.